# Shell Script Error: "Unexpected End of File"

Tags: shell, sh

I've been getting the following error after adding code (line; 78 - 134)
Before adding this code everything went fine!.
Some extra information; I'm using this .sh file as a raw github file "linked" to another .sh file. It's code to install/self-host a discord bot (based on Nadeko).

> $root/TCU_installer_latest.sh: line 151: syntax error: unexpected end
> of file

(the .sh file is called "TCU_installer_latest.sh")

This is the code;

```
1. #!/bin/sh
2. clear
3. echo "TCU Installer started."
4. 
5. if hash git 1>/dev/null 2>&1
6. then
7.     echo ""
8.     echo "Git Installed."
9. else
10.     clear
11.     echo "Git is not installed."
12.     echo 'Git installation; "sudo apt-get install git"'
13.     echo ""
14.     echo 'Press CTRL + C to exit.'
15.     echo "Program will automatically exit after 60 seconds."
16.     sleep 60s
17.     exit 0
18. fi
19. 
20. 
21. if hash dotnet 1>/dev/null 2>&1
22. then
23.     echo ""
24.     echo "Dotnet installed."
25. else
26.     echo ""
27.     echo "Dotnet is not installed."
28.     echo 'Dotnet installation; "https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download"'
29.     echo ""
30.     echo 'Press CTRL + C to exit.'
31.     echo "Program will automatically exit after 60 seconds."
32.     sleep 60s
33.     exit 0
34. fi
35. 
36. root=$(pwd)
37. tempdir=TCU_Temp
38. 
39. rm -r "$tempdir" 1>/dev/null 2>&1
40. mkdir "$tempdir"
41. cd "$tempdir"
42. 
43. clear
44. echo "Downloading TCU, please wait."
45. echo ""
46. echo "This process usually takes about 15 seconds."
47. sleep 5s
48. git clone -b Latest_version --recursive --depth 1 (link removed but works fine in actual code)
49. clear
50. echo "TCU downloaded."
51. 
52. echo ""
53. echo "Downloading TCU dependencies"
54. echo ""
55. echo "This process usually takes about 10 seconds."
56. sleep 5s
57. cd "$root/$tempdir/TCU"
58. dotnet restore
59. clear
60. echo "TCU Dependecies are downloaded"
61. 
62. echo ""
63. echo "Building TCU for you!"
64. echo ""
65. echo "This process usually takes about 10 seconds."
66. sleep 5s
67. dotnet build --configuration Release
68. clear
69. echo "Build done."
70. sleep 3s
71. 
72. cd "$root"
73. 
74. if [ ! -d TCU ]
75. then
76.     mv "$tempdir"/TCU TCU
77. else
78.     echo 'You already have a directory called "TCU" in this folder.'
79.     echo ""
80.     cd $root
81.     choice=5
82.     echo "1. Delete the original TCU folder and retry your download."
83.     echo '2. Rename the original TCU folder (-> "TCU_Old") and retry your download. (recommended)'
84.     echo "3. Don't touch the original TCU folder and retry your download."
85.     echo "4. Exit."
86.     echo ""
87.     echo -n "Choose one of above options (to force quit -> CTRL + C)"
88.     while [ $choice -eq 5 ]; do
89.     read choice
90.     if [ $choice -eq 1 ] ; then
91.       echo ""
92.       echo 'Deleting "TCU"'
93.       rm -rf TCU
94.       sleep 2s
95.       echo ""
96.       echo 'Retrying TCU latest/stable build.'
97.       sleep 3s
98.       bash $root/TCU_installer_latest
99. 
100.       else if [ $choice -q 2 ]; then
101.         echo ""
102.         echo 'Renaming "TCU" to "TCU_Old"'
103.         mv $root/TCU TCU_Old
104.         sleep 2s
105.         echo ""
106.         echo 'Retrying TCU latest/stable build.'
107.         sleep 3s
108.         bash $root/TCU_installer_latest
109. 
110.         else if [ $choice -q 3 ]; then
111.           echo ""
112.           echo 'Retrying TCU latest/stable build.'
113.           sleep 3s
114.           bash $root/TCU_installer_latest
115.           else if [ $choice -q 4 ]; then
116.             echo ""
117.             echo "Exciting.."
118.             sleep 2s
119.             cd $root
120.             exit 0
121.             else
122.               clear
123.               echo "1. Delete the original TCU folder and retry your download."
124.               echo '2. Rename the original TCU folder (-> "TCU_Old") and retry your download. (recommended)'
125.               echo "3. Don't touch the original TCU folder and retry your download."
126.               echo "4. Exit."
127.               echo ""
128.               echo -n "Choose one of above options (to force quit -> CTRL + C)"
129.               choice=5
130.           fi
131.         fi
132.       fi
133.     fi
134. done
135. 
136. rm -r "$tempdir"
137. clear
138. echo "Installation Complete."
139. echo "TCU has been installed successfully!"
140. echo ""
141. echo "Thanks for using TCU <3"
142. echo ""
143. echo 'Press CTRL + C to exit.'
144. echo "Program will automatically exit after 60 seconds."
145. cd "$root"
146. rm "$root/TCU_installer_latest.sh"
147. sleep 60s
148. 
149. cd $root
150. exit 0
```

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Have you run it through shellcheck?

Comment: You should be using `elif` -- there is no `else if` in shell.

Comment: cut/paste your code into https://shellcheck.net . Be sure to include the first line. If errors corrected  solve your problem,  please delete your Q ELSE update your Q with corrected code. Good luck.